# How to store short date format to db?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I use Core Data and I want to store this formatted date to db, field type is date, how can I do this?

```
date formatted: 2010-10-31
```

I hope I explained my scenario. Sorry for my English. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question here is ***why*** you would want to do this.  It is best to store the NSDate as an NSDate, then apply any view changes you need on the fly with NSDateFormatter.

However, so I can get some Rep Points, I will answer the question.  You can store the pre-formatted date as an NSString, not an NSDate.